# Mail system in my install is broken: Missing bundle property on entity of type node

Tags: civimail, email, error

I had an install of CiviCRM which had CiviMail and all email working fine. I was using sendgrid to deliver the email, and ran out of credits. Unsent mail had piled up in the Civi system and I attempted to clear caches and temporarily had the system in debug mode. Now I can not send mail via CiviMail nor via individual emails selected from a search, for example. Both give the same error about missing bundle property on entity of type node. The only email I can send is the test of the SMTP server settings from /civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1

This problem started while running 4.6.16. I attempted an upgrade to 4.7.12 and get the same error, so that did not fix it.

entire backtrace message with minor edits for privacy:

```
LOCATION  http://esoduplicate.evanstonsymphony.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?_qf_Email_display=true&qfKey=df6b23737309806ea2bf2ae9b9b9cbc1_2533
REFERRER  http://esoduplicate.evanstonsymphony.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?_qf_Advanced_display=true&qfKey=df6b23737309806ea2bf2ae9b9b9cbc1_2533
MESSAGE  $backTrace = 
  #0 /path-to-site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(454): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) 
  #1 /path-to-site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(57): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(EntityMalformedException))
  #2 /path-to-site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4)) 
  #3 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "search", "advanced") 
  #4 /path-to-site/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3)) 
  #5 /path-to-site/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #6 {main}

$Fatal Error Details = array(3) { 
  ["message"]=> string(47) "Missing bundle property on entity of type node." 
  ["code"]=> NULL
  ["exception"]=> object(EntityMalformedException)#269 (7) { 
    ["message":protected]=> string(47) "Missing bundle property on entity of type node." 
    ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" 
    ["code":protected]=> int(0) 
    ["file":protected]=> string(52) "/path-to-site/includes/common.inc" 
    ["line":protected]=> int(7907) 
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(21) { 
      [0]=> array(4) { 
        ["file"]=> string(69) "/path-to-site/modules/field/field.multilingual.inc" 
        ["line"]=> int(268) 
        ["function"]=> string(18) "entity_extract_ids" 
        ["args"]=> array(2) { 
          [0]=> string(4) "node" 
          [1]=> bool(false) 
        } 
      } 
      [1]=> array(4) {
        ["file"]=> string(59) "/path-to-site/modules/field/field.module" 
        ["line"]=> int(941) 
        ["function"]=> string(14) "field_language" 
        ["args"]=> array(4) { 
          [0]=> string(4) "node" 
          [1]=> bool(false) 
          [2]=> string(4) "body" 
          [3]=> NULL 
        } 
     } 
     [2]=> array(4) { 
       ["file"]=> string(81) "/path-to-site/sites/all/modules/esoCiviMail/esoCiviMail.module" 
       ["line"]=> int(190) 
       ["function"]=> string(15) "field_get_items" 
       ["args"]=> array(3) { 
         [0]=> string(4) "node" 
         [1]=> bool(false) 
         [2]=> string(4) "body" 
       } 
     } 
     [3]=> array(4) { 
       ["file"]=> string(77) "/path-to-site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php" 
       ["line"]=> int(240) 
       ["function"]=> string(31) "esoCiviMail_civicrm_tokenValues" 
       ["args"]=> array(5) { 
         [0]=> &array(1) { 
           [2]=> array(9) { 
             ["contact_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
             ["sort_name"]=> string(11) "Example, Tim" 
             ["display_name"]=> string(10) "Tim Example" 
             ["do_not_email"]=> string(1) "0" 
             ["preferred_mail_format"]=> string(4) "Both" 
             ["is_deceased"]=> string(1) "0" 
             ["email_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
             ["email"]=> string(19) "tim[at]example.com" 
             ["on_hold"]=> string(1) "0" 
           } 
         } 
         [1]=> array(1) { 
           [0]=> int(2) 
         } 
         [2]=> NULL 
         [3]=> array(0) { } 
         [4]=> NULL 
       } 
     } 
     [4]=> array(6) { 
       ["file"]=> string(88) "/path-to-site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php" 
       ["line"]=> int(85) 
       ["function"]=> string(8) "runHooks" 
       ["class"]=> string(14) "CRM_Utils_Hook" 
       ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
       ["args"]=> array(9) {
```

Comment: When I do a quick Google search on the error I get the impression its origin is drupal (specially the entity system). Do you have some extra drupal civicrm modules installed?

Comment: I figured it out. It was a custom module to supply custom tokens which we had written and interacted with CiviMail. I think a date change trigger made the problems both appear on the same day and made debugging harder. Plus I don't really understand why it impacted all mail, even if it used no part of the module and the non-CiviMail part of the system. I guess the hook impacts all mail: esoCiviMail_civicrm_tokens

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to be a problem with the mail system, as you say it's some custom code which prevented mails being generated or sent.

*I see you've identified this - great! And yes, all tokens are generated for each email sent, even if they aren't used - so token generators need to handle situations like this.*

To help others - I've reformatted the backtrace so it's more readable, and removed some personal details (possibly your own).

The real problem here was that the entity, as provided to [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7.x), was being passed as FALSE - perhaps because the module had failed to look up a matching user account?

SO instead of (pseudocode) -

```
$user = esoCiviMail_get_related_user($contact_id);
$foo = field_get_items('user', $user);
// generate tokens
```

you'd want to do

```
if ($user = esoCiviMail_get_related_user($contact_id) {
  $foo = field_get_items('user', $user);
  // generate tokens
}
// else { 
//   ... generate "no-result" default tokens 
// }
```

Possibly you want the esoCiviMail module to check if a node was correctly found, and if not then return some default (possibly blank) token value to the CiviCRM hook it's implementing.

If the contact really has an email of `tim[at]example.com` instead of `tim@example.com` I'd expect this to trigger some issues.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem was a node lookup not a user lookup - same underlying logic holds.

Answer (score 1):

A custom module triggered this problem.

```
description =  Define custom tokens CiviMail
dependencies[] = civicrm
files[] = esoCiviMail.module


function esoCiviMail_civicrm_tokenValues() /* */
function esoCiviMail_civicrm_tokens(&$tokens) {
// ...
$nid=$node*1; //node id of next concert promo page //
$input_lines="";
// $node does not resolve--THIS IS BROKEN AFTER CONCERT 1
$node = node_load($nid);
$my_field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
  if ($my_field_items) {
    $my_field_first_item = reset($my_field_items);
    $input_lines = $my_field_first_item['value'];
  }
}
```