# Can I turn off Drupal cron while the CiviCRM upgrade script is running?

Tags: drupal, upgrade, error, cron

I want to know if it is a bad idea to turn off cron while in the middle of upgrading the CiviCRM?

Below is my original post, but now I see that this information is irrelevant/unrelated.

I am upgrading our CiviCRM from 4.3.8 to 4.7.13. On my local dev environment, the update went basically fine, but I didn't have cron turned on. On my remote test site, which does have cron runs, the update seems to be stalled. Watchdog is showing cron errors for the last 3 hours with seemingly no progress. I suspect that Drupal's cron is trying to run and everything is being stalled because of this error, that could be caused from jumping so many versions. What I want to know is if I can open another terminal window and turn off cron until I'm done running the update script or is this a bad idea, especially since it's already running?

In case it's important, here is the cron error:

```
error  cron  EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7953 of /var/www/html/mydomain/docroot/includes/common.inc).
```

Comment: The error you report is the same as in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/mail-system-in-my-install-is-broken-missing-bundle-property-on-entity-of-type-n . That had to do with a custom module that uses drupal entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard for Drupal cron is to only run it every 8 hours.  Unless you use modules that expect a more frequent update (e.g. to pull in RSS feeds in a timely manner) you should be fine turning it off for a day.