# CiviMail problem; possible Cron Error: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids()

Tags: civimail, drupal, cron

After making core updates in Drupal commons, from 7.37 to 7.50, scheduled Civi mails are not being sent. Cron jobs are still set up. Before this update, we've been using it for years with no known issues. Using CiviCRM 4.8.7. Currently trying to upgrade now but there are other roadblocks also.

Watchdog shows the following error for the time of the scheduled mailing:

```
error    cron     EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7953 of /var/www/html/example/docroot/includes/common.inc).
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/mail-system-in-my-install-is-broken-missing-bundle-property-on-entity-of-type-n . Here the problem was caused by a custom module that uses the drupal entity system.

Comment: All we did was upgrade Drupal Core. Then it stopped working. I am under the impression that that doesn't include custom work. How would I be able to tell if there is a custom module using the "drupal entity system" and what it might be and why does it affect CiviCRM?

Comment: In the referenced question the problem was the implementation of a custom hook (namely hook_civicrm_tokenValues). The hook was executed when an email was sent (it generated custom tokens) and throw an error. The hook called drupal functions. In your case, did you install drupal dependent CiviCRM extensions, or CiviCRM specific drupal modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this cron error is unrelated to CiviMail going out. I resolved the problem by changing the group owner and permissions of the `/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c` folder, which was effecting `/mail.log`. The group permissions was changed to root, which won't work for the mail.

I am still getting this cron error, but know now that it probably has to do with Drupal alone.